# How can I connect to Oracle database by ConnectorX Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, connection

I am trying to connect Oracle database by ConnectorX Python
When my database has 1 server 1 port, I can connect normally. But when my database have many server and many port. I don’t know how to connect with ConnetorX.

I tried to connect by DNS the same cx_Oracle. But It was fail. If you have any solution for this problem. Please share with me

Comment: If you are using an Oracle RAC configuration then you should get your DBA to provide you with the DNS "SCAN Name" and port for the cluster. That will be a single hostname that will automatically resolve and rotate between cluster nodes so you don't have to worry about which one is available or support a huge TNS connect descriptor.

Comment: Do you need ConnectorX?  Have you tried [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) in Thin mode? This can be faster than cx_Oracle.  And have you tuned `arraysize` when fetching data?